# DeprecationWarning: HTTPResponse.getheader() is deprecated and will be removed in urllib3 v2.1.0. Instead use HTTPResponse.headers.get() with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, httpresponse, urllib3, deprecation-warning

Every time when i run my selenium script it shows some warnings. Can anyone explain me the reason of the warnings and how to solve it.

```
C:\Users\1154-Talha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py:418: DeprecationWarning: HTTPResponse.getheader() is deprecated and will be removed in urllib3 v2.1.0. Instead use HTTPResponse.headers.get(name, default).
  if resp.getheader('Content-Type') is not None:
C:\Users\1154-Talha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py:419: DeprecationWarning: HTTPResponse.getheader() is deprecated and will be removed in urllib3 v2.1.0. Instead use HTTPResponse.headers.get(name, default).
  content_type = resp.getheader('Content-Type').split(';')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Update the question with your Selenium script.

Answer (score 1):

[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) requires [**urllib3**](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/)

[image: urllib3]

[`getheader()` is deprecated now and will be removed in urllib3 v2.1.0](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/pull/2814). Instead with Selenium we need to use *`HTTPResponse.headers.get(name, default)`*.

---

### Details

This issue was discussed in the thread [DeprecationWarning: HTTPResponse.getheader() is deprecated and will be removed in urllib3 v2.1.0.](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11313) and was addressed through pull request [Replace response.getheader() with response.headers.get()](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/11308) which replaces `response.getheader()` with `response.headers.get()` deprecated in urllib3 1.26.13 which will prevent lots of deprecation warnings when using the [selenium 4.6.1](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/4.6.1/) and above.

---

### Solution

Upgrade to ***Selenium 4.6.1*** or above.

Answer (score -1):

`HTTPResponse.getheader()` is deprecated and will be removed in urllib3 v2.1.0. Instead use `HTTPResponse.headers.get(name, default)`